# Extracting text from a string based on sentence structure

Tags: php, string

This may be asked already and if so, I apologize, but I've been searching and I'm not sure how to phrase my question.

I have this text string:

```
$text = "You have received a message.  The quote request is from Cade Carrier; and is for these items: Tires: 195 60 15 - Direct Input (2).";
```

What I need to pull out is *Cade Carrier*.  I know that the name of the customer will always be followed by a semicolon (as in the sample above), and will always be preceded by *The quote request is from* (with a space after *from*).

How do I go about pulling out the text that I need from this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex will do:

```
preg_match('/The quote request is from ([^;]+);/', $text, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

Match the given text and then capture `()` any character `[]` that is not `^` a semi-colon one or more `+` up to the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

on a non-regex matter, you can extract like this

```
$text = "You have received a message.  The quote request is from Cade Carrier; and is for these items: Tires: 195 60 15 - Direct Input (2).";

$text2 = strstr($text, ";", true); // get everything before the first ;
$from = strpos($a, "from ") + 5; // +5 for the 5 chars of "from "
$str = substr($a, $from);
var_dump($str); // string(12) "Cade Carrier"
```